# Summing data by extracting month from full date

Tags: sql, function, date, time

I want to count all the persons by month. right now it is grouping by day.

```
Select 
    TRUNC(ed.COVERAGE_START_DATE),
    Count(Distinct Egpa.Person_Id)
```

Comment: show us your table structure

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  When posting a question, please include as much detail as you can.  The bare minimum for a question like this would be the database type (SQL, Oracle, etc.), the table structures (column names, data types) of each of your tables, sample data from each of your tables, and the query or queries you have tried.  If more than one table is used, include JOIN conditions.  Finally, include a description of what you're hoping to accomplish and a sample output that clearly shows the result you want to see from your query.  Please edit your post to include these, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try either:

```
SELECT Month, Count(Person)
  FROM Table
 GROUP BY month
```

OR

```
SELECT DATEPART(Month, YourDate) Month
  FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY DATEPART(Month, YourDate)
```